# How can I write a regex to extract data preceding and following a specific expression in a text file?

Tags: javascript, regex

**Problem:**
I have a logfile containing data and I want to extract the data preceding and following a specific expression. I've taken a screenshot of the logfile and highlighted the data I want. You can view the screenshot of the logfile here: [logfile.JPG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rtbmw.jpg). Since the length, format, and position of the data never change in this line, I am simplifying by showing a specific line from the logfile:

> `Aug 23 07:25:43 Astrance 125_Heater_1.30.02.0124_d[11421]: 2023-08-23T07:25:43.402421|304|4|1250025|virtual bool CReadTempStep::SPIIsSatisfied():129|Temperatures 39.998318 39.982665 40.167597 40.167027`

I am interested in extracting the timestamp at the beginning `Aug 23 07:25:43` and the four numbers at the end `39.998318 39.982665 40.167597 40.167027`. I'm looking for a single regular expression that can return one match.

**My solution so far written in JavaScript:**

Regex1, Getting the timestamp (`Aug 23 07:25:43`):

> `.*(?= Astrance.*Temperatures)`

Regex2, Getting the four numbers (`39.998318 39.982665 40.167597 40.167027`):

> `(?<= Astrance.*Temperatures).*`

**Question:**

How can I combine Regex1 and Regex2 into a single regex that returns one match?

**Expected answer:**

It would be great if somebody provides me a tiny javascript program which returns me all the matches in a list as follows:

```
MatchList = [
   [ 'Aug 23 07:25:43', '39.998318 39.982665 40.167597 40.167027' ],
   [ 'Aug 23 07:25:45', '39.999999 39.576576 40.676767 40.334444' ],
   [ 'Aug 23 07:25:47', '39.456777 39.734534 40.898899 40.898999' ],
    ...
   ]
```

**Solution (Thanks to the community):**

```
// read local logfile into a variable:

var fs = require("fs");
var logFileString = fs.readFileSync("./sys", "utf-8");

// use regex and write the matches into a list:

const regex = /^(.*?)\s*Astrance.*Temperatures\s*(.*)/gm;
const matches = Array.from([...logFileString.matchAll(regex)], x => [x[1], x[2]]);

console.log(matches);
```

Comment: Using capturing groups: `^(.*?)\s*Astrance.*Temperatures\s*(.*)`, see  https://regex101.com/r/l30gZI/1

Comment: I don't know JS Regex syntax, but usually every part of the Regex between simple brackets () is captured as a result. In your case, (.*)(?= Astrance.*Temperatures)(.*) should work and return both the timestamp and the 4 last numbers

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for your solution. How I am implementing your solution in a javascript? THX and BR Marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
const text = 'Aug 23 07:25:43 Astrance 125_Heater_1.30.02.0124_d[11421]: 2023-08-23T07:25:43.402421|304|4|1250025|virtual bool CReadTempStep::SPIIsSatisfied():129|Temperatures 39.998318 39.982665 40.167597 40.167027';
const regex = /^(.*?)\s*Astrance.*Temperatures\s*(.*)/gm;
const matches = Array.from([...text.matchAll(regex)], x => [x[1], x[2]]);
console.log(matches);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Nua6dM/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of any line (since the `m` flag is used)
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `Astrance.*Temperatures` - `Astrance`, then any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible and then `Temperatures`
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(.*)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Hi here is a working example:

```js
const string = 'Aug 23 07:25:43 Astrance 125_Heater_1.30.02.0124_d[11421]: 2023-08-23T07:25:43.402421|304|4|1250025|virtual bool CReadTempStep::SPIIsSatisfied():129|Temperatures 39.998318 39.982665 40.167597 40.167027'

const pattern = /(.*(?= Astrance))|((?<=Temperatures ).*)/g


console.log(string.match(pattern)[0])
console.log(string.match(pattern)[2])
```